# Can't match StatusBar and View background color

Tags: react-native, background-color, statusbar, react-native-cli

I spent a few hours trying to solve this, but it seems I just cannot find an answer. Nothing works.
I've tried various combinations of the following:

- hided the status bar (didn't hide) to have an expanded view
- used translucent, barStyle, etc

For some reason, which I'm ignoring, I cannot get rid of the style that Android is imposing.
If I set the color to be, for example, 'black', the StatusBar, regardless of what I do, will have a toned-down version of 'black'.

No matter which combination of the options above I try, I can't even hide it, like many videogames and apps out there.

P.S.: I also tried changing the SafeAreaView component to View, but the issue remains the same.

The following is my code

```
import { SafeAreaView, StatusBar, View } from "react-native"
import { CalculadoraScreen } from "./src/screens/CalculadoraScreen";
import { style } from './src/theme/appTheme';


const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{
      ...style.background,
      }}>
      <StatusBar 
        backgroundColor={style.background.backgroundColor}
        // translucent={true}
        // hidden={true}
        barStyle={'light-content'}
      />
      <CalculadoraScreen/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Phone model: Google Pixel 4a (physical device)

OS: Android 13

React Native CLI

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.1"
  }
```

Edit:

- Added RN CLI

Comment: Hey, community, before downvoting, let me know the specific reason behind your potential downvote without being vague so I can improve my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to **turn my PC on and off** to get every buggy property of the  component to work as expected.

So, if you're encountering a similar issue, simply restart everything, and you should be good to go.

I've spent a considerable amount of time searching for a solution here, but none of the variations of this question have been 'resolved' yet.

Answer (score 0):

add this in app.json

```
"androidStatusBar": {
"translucent": false
    },
```

then add the expo-status bar component in your app.js file

```
<StatusBar
style={"light"}
backgroundColor="transparent"
/>
```

Comment: I'm not using expo